# postgresql insert into from select

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two tables table1 and test_table1 which have the same schema.

Both tables have rows/data and pk id's starting from 1.

I would like to do:

```
insert into test_table1 select * from table1;
```

but this fails due to the pk values from table1 existing in test_table1.

Way around it would be to specify columns and leave the pk column out, but for some reason thats not working either:

e.g. 
NOTE - no pk columns in query below

```
insert into test_table1 (col1, col2,..., coln) select col1,col2,...,coln from table1;
```

returns

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_table1_pkey"
>   DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.

I know this works in MySql, is this just due to Postgresql? Anyway around it?

EDIT:

Both tables have primary keys and sequence set.

Since it wasn't clear - tables don't have the same data.
I would just like to add rows from table1 to test_table1.

For answers telling me to exclude primary key from the query - I did as I said before.

Comment: Which version? If you are using 9.5 `INSERT .. ON CONFLICT` may work for you.

Comment: You have defined your table to have a primary key and you are inserting a value to it that exists already.  It worked in MySQL because your MySQL table didn't have a unique primary key defined on it.  Give us the table schema for your test tables (including constraints) for a full answer.  (should clarify...do the rows already exist in test_table1 and you're trying to insert again, or are you looking to update the values in test_table1 to be the same as table1?)

Comment: List all the columns *except* the primary key.  A new primary key will be assigned, however.

Comment: I've edited the question - pk column was never in the query but it does exist on both tables with sequence.

Comment: If you have excluded primary key column from insert query and pk constraint error still occures there will be only one reason.

Comment: Sequence current value is invalid. You have to set sequence Current value to max value of pk column

Comment: As i have written on answer.

Comment: @TalehIbrahimli tnx Taleh, last line of your comment would have done the job so I accepted your answer, but because I had little experience with Postgresql didn't expect the sequences to get messed up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove pk column from columns of query

```
insert into test_table1 (col2,..., coln) select col2,...,coln from table1;
```

If it still fails maybe you have not sequence on pk columns.
 Create sequence on already existing pk column

```
create sequence test_table1_seq;
ALTER TABLE test_table1 
    ALTER COLUMN col1 SET DEFAULT nextval('test_table1_seq'::regclass);
```

And update sequence value to current

```
SELECT setval('test_table1_seq', (SELECT MAX(col1) FROM test_table1));
```

Comment: Hi Taleh, tnx for the reply, I've edited the question - pk column was never in the query but it does exist on both tables with sequence.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://hcmc.uvic.ca/blogs/index.php?blog=22&p=8105&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1) helped me solve my problem, not sure what went wrong:

---

> #### How to fix PostgreSQL error "duplicate key violates unique constraint"
>
> If you get this message when trying to insert data into a PostgreSQL database:
>
> > ERROR: duplicate key violates unique constraint
>
> That likely means that the primary key sequence in the table you're working with has somehow become out of sync, likely because of a mass import process (or something along those lines). Call it a "bug by design", but it seems that you have to manually reset the a primary key index after restoring from a dump file. At any rate, to see if your values are out of sync, run these two commands:
>
> ```
> SELECT MAX(the_primary_key) FROM the_table;
> SELECT nextval('the_primary_key_sequence');
> ```
>
> If the first value is higher than the second value, your sequence is out of sync. Back up your PG database (just in case), then run thisL
>
> ```
> SELECT setval('the_primary_key_sequence', (SELECT MAX(the_primary_key) FROM the_table)+1);
> ```
>
> That will set the sequence to the next available value that's higher than any existing primary key in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You rather would want to do a `UPDATE JOIN` like

```
UPDATE test_table1 AS v 
SET col1 = s.col1,
col2 = s.col2,
col3 = s.col3,
.....
colN = s.colN
FROM table1 AS s
WHERE v.id = s.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is an upsert.

```
with upsert as (
    update test_table1 tt
    set col1 = t.col1,
        col2 = t.col2,
        col3 = t.col3
    from table1 t
    where t.id = tt.id 
    returning *
)
insert into test_table1(id, col1, col2, col3)
select id, col1,col2,col3
from table1
where not exists (select * from upsert)
```